# Spring Batch ResourcelessTransactionManager messes with persistence.xml?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am working on an application and have been asked to implement a scheduled spring batch job. I have set up a configuration file where I set a `@Bean` `ResourcelessTransactionManager` but it seems to mess with the `persistence.xml`.

There is already a persistence xml in an other module, there is no compilation error. I get a `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` when I am requesting a page that returns a view item.

This is the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: txManager,transactionManager
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:365)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.determineTransactionManager(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:271)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
at com.mypackage.services.MyClassService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e8bf16f.registryEvents(<generated>)
at com.mypackage.controllers.MyClassSearchView.init(MyClassSearchView.java:75)
... 168 more
```

Is there a way to tell spring batch to use the data source defined in the persistence.xml of the other module or maybe is this caused by something else?

Comment: Which transaction manager do you want to use? The one defined in persistence.xml or the `ResourcelessTransactionManager` you set up?

Comment: I want the ResourcelessTransactionManager for spring batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created separate BatchScheduler java class as below and included it in BatchConfiguration java class. I am sharing both the classes. BatchConfiguration contains another jpaTransactionManager.

```
    import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

    @Configuration
    @EnableScheduling
    public class BatchScheduler {

@Bean
public ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager() {
    return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
}

@Bean
public MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean mapJobRepositoryFactory(
        ResourcelessTransactionManager resourcelessTransactionManager) throws Exception {

    MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new 
            MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(resourcelessTransactionManager);

    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository(
        MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean factory) throws Exception {
    return factory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher(JobRepository jobRepository) {
    SimpleJobLauncher launcher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    launcher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    return launcher;
}

    }
```

BatchConfiguration contains another jpaTransactionManager.

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
    import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
    import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
    import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
    import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
    import org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
    import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
    import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskScheduler;
    import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;

    import trade.api.common.constants.Constants;
    import trade.api.entity.SecurityEntity;
    import trade.api.trade.batch.item.processor.SecurityItemProcessor;
    import trade.api.trade.batch.item.reader.NseSecurityReader;
    import trade.api.trade.batch.notification.listener.SecurityJobCompletionNotificationListener;
    import trade.api.trade.batch.tasklet.SecurityReaderTasklet;
    import trade.api.vo.SecurityVO;

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @EnableScheduling
    @Import({OhlcMonthBatchConfiguration.class, OhlcWeekBatchConfiguration.class, OhlcDayBatchConfiguration.class, OhlcMinuteBatchConfiguration.class})
    public class BatchConfiguration {

        private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;

        /*
           Load the properties
        */
        @Value("${database.driver}")
        private String databaseDriver;
        @Value("${database.url}")
        private String databaseUrl;
        @Value("${database.username}")
        private String databaseUsername;
        @Value("${database.password}")
        private String databasePassword;

        @Autowired
        public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

        @Autowired
        private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

        @Bean
        public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
            return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
        }

        //second, minute, hour, day of month, month, day(s) of week
        //@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 21 * * 1-5") on week days
        @Scheduled(cron="${schedule.insert.security}")
        public void importSecuritySchedule() throws Exception {

            System.out.println("Job Started at :" + new Date());

            JobParameters param = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID",
                    String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters();

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(importSecuritesJob(), param);

            System.out.println("Job finished with status :" + execution.getStatus());
        }

        @Bean SecurityJobCompletionNotificationListener securityJobCompletionNotificationListener() {
            return new SecurityJobCompletionNotificationListener();
        }




        //Import Equity OHLC End

        //Import Equity Start
        // tag::readerwriterprocessor[]

        @Bean
        public SecurityReaderTasklet securityReaderTasklet() {
            return new SecurityReaderTasklet();
        }

        @Bean
        @StepScope
        public NseSecurityReader<SecurityVO> nseSecurityReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext["+Constants.SECURITY_DOWNLOAD_FILE+"]}") String pathToFile) throws IOException {

            NseSecurityReader<SecurityVO> reader = new NseSecurityReader<SecurityVO>();
            reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
            reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(pathToFile));
            reader.setLineMapper(new DefaultLineMapper<SecurityVO>() {{
                setLineTokenizer(new DelimitedLineTokenizer() {{
                    setNames(new String[] { "symbol", "nameOfCompany", "series", "dateOfListing", "paidUpValue", "marketLot", "isinNumber", "faceValue" });
                }});
                setFieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<SecurityVO>() {{
                    setTargetType(SecurityVO.class);
                }});
            }});
            return reader;
        }


        @Bean
        public SecurityItemProcessor processor() {
            return new SecurityItemProcessor();
        }

        @Bean
        public JpaItemWriter<SecurityEntity> writer() {
            JpaItemWriter<SecurityEntity> writer = new JpaItemWriter<SecurityEntity>();
            writer.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
            return writer;
        }
        // end::readerwriterprocessor[]

        // tag::jobstep[]
        @Bean
        public Job importSecuritesJob() throws IOException {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("importSecuritesJob")
                    .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                    .listener(securityJobCompletionNotificationListener())
                    .start(downloadSecurityStep())
                    .next(insertSecurityStep())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step downloadSecurityStep() throws IOException {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("downloadSecurityStep")
                    .tasklet(securityReaderTasklet())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public Step insertSecurityStep() throws IOException {
            return stepBuilderFactory.get("insertSecurityStep")
                    .transactionManager(jpaTransactionManager())
                    .<SecurityVO, SecurityEntity> chunk(100)
                    .reader(nseSecurityReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                    .processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer())
                    .build();
        }
        // end::jobstep[]

        //Import Equity End

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName(databaseDriver);
            dataSource.setUrl(databaseUrl);
            dataSource.setUsername(databaseUsername);
            dataSource.setPassword(databasePassword);
            return dataSource;
        }


        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            lef.setPackagesToScan("trade.api.entity");
            lef.setDataSource(dataSource());
            lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
            lef.setJpaProperties(new Properties());
            return lef;
        }


        @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
            jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
            jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
            jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            return jpaVendorAdapter;
        }

        @Bean
        @Qualifier("jpaTransactionManager")
        public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
               return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        }

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer dataProperties(Environment environment) throws IOException {
            String[] activeProfiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
            final PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
            ppc.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath*:application-"+activeProfiles[0]+".properties"));
            return ppc;
        }
        //// Import Security End
    }
```

Comment: My Batch configuration class is similar with your BatchScheduler class. My problem is when an @Entity object is requested from the jpa. Before I setup the batch config everything worked fine. After the config the batch is working but the pages that bring back orm data are giving a NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException. It seems like the persistence.xml conflicts with my BatchConfig but I want my model to be able to see the persistence.xml configuration for the database and my BatchConfig the ResourcelessTransactionManager .

Comment: For  txManager,transactionManager add @Qualifier (I have added it for my jpaTransactionManager. For batch steps I have provided the transaction manager name in steps(refer the above code). For Application methods use `    @Transactional("<your qualifier name>") 
    public void doSomethingInBusinessData() { ... } `

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. There was a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean located in an other configuration file. I set it as `@Primary` and now the problem is fixed. Thanks everyone for the help.